# Avoid first level cache for an entity in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have an entity which is updated externally (using triggers, stored procedures). This means the entity can change without my knowledge in the same session, and it is required for me that I always perform a database hit, and never use the entity from the first level cache.

Is this possible using NHibernate (or actually, Castle ActiveRecord)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cold use a `IStatelessSession` instead of `ISession` to disable first level cache:

```
using (ISessionFactory sf = cfg.BuildSessionFactory())
using (IStatelessSession session = sf.OpenStatelessSession())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In ActiveRecord: StatelessSessionScope